# Proving that $f(x) = xg(x)$ for some $g$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm having some trouble proving the following:

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable at $x = 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Prove that there exists a funcion $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ continuous at $x = 0$ such that $f(x) = xg(x)$.

So because $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$ we know that the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)- f(0)}{x - 0} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

So my plan was to define $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$. The only problem is that, if we do this the domain of $g$ will be $\mathbb R \setminus \{ 0\}$ and I need it to be $\mathbb R$. Is there any way to avoid this problem with the domain? How can I prove this?

Comment: Define $g(0)$ appropriately.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yes, thanks.

Comment: You can define $g(0)=f'(0)$. That way $g$ would be continuous at $0$ and $f(x)=xg(x)~~~\forall~x$.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(0)$ to  be

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

(Which exists since $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$)

and $g(x)$ for $x$  not equal to $0$ to be $$f(x)/x$$

Then $f(x)=xg(x)$  for all $x$ (This true at $0$ since $g(0)$ exists)

$g(x)$ is obviously continuous at $0$ (since $g(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$).